# Piping Windows command output to another command

Tags: windows, cmd

I can't seem to find a way to do this. In Windows, is it not possible to send the output of a file I searched for using `dir /s /b` to another command that would open the file all in one go? Currently I do:

```
C:\> dir /s /b My_file.txt
C:\found_here\MyFile.txt
```

and then I copy that output and go:

```
C:\> notepad c:\found_here\MyFile.txt
```

Shouldn't I be able to use `|>` or some such to do this in one step?

Comment: use `for /f`: `for /f "delims=" %%# in ('dir /s /b file.txt') do notepad %%#`. %# instead of %%# if via cmd.

Comment: @Regejok Thanks! That works. Suppose I generalize this into a batch file and pass "file*.txt" instead of "file.txt", do I end up opening every hit in notepad? Is there a way to complain if `dir /s /b` results in more than one hit?

Comment: It would open every match, yes. Every .txt file that starts with "file", in that case. You can either use no asterisk to only get one file, open the first match and then break out of the loop with `goto`/`exit`, or open the last match by saving the result in a variable and then opening the variable. Anything else would be slightly more difficult, but can possibly be done with `findstr` or some other method.